# SpriteKit, XCode 8, Swift 3 MGGetBoolAnswer is not available in the simulator

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift3, xcode8

My console is filling up with these messages every time I run my app in the Xcode simulator. Does anyone know what this means, or how I can get rid of it?

This is the full message:

> 2016-09-14 19:28:51.042 SpaceGameDeluxe[3182:49139] SKUtil.m:
>   MGGetBoolAnswer is not available in the simulator.

Comment: I'm getting that too, but based on past experience with these weird logs in beta and low-point-release versions of Xcode, I'm assuming it'll stop happening in subsequent builds.

Comment: I was able to narrow it down to SKTextureAtlas being the culprit

Comment: @Knight0fDragon im actually not using any texture atlases. Im planning to, but havent done so yet

Comment: well then it is probably tied to SKTexture

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've been getting these messages as well. I found a thread on the apple dev forum where an apple staff member said:

> by fbroom on Sep 15, 2016 1:22 PM
>
> This is a harmless message. It will be removed in the next release. Sorry for the confusion.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/62983